# Security Concerns: Sending an access token within a POST request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm developing a simple CMS and to create, update and delete posts I am sending AJAX requests.

**This is how a user adds a post to the blog:**

1. The user's email and password are sent to server `(login.php)` using AJAX via a POST request.
2. If the user ID and password match, the user will get an `accessToken` which is saved in the cookies.

```js
$.ajax({
    url: 'add-post.php',
    data: {
        user_id: 123,
        accessToken: 'f0230ce1-5330-41bf-9600-592cfdf3cf0c',
        post_title: 'sample post title'
    }
});
```

My question is that if it's acceptable to send the `accessToken` via the POST request to the server? Is there any security concerns that I should be aware of when doing this?

Comment: sure.. why not? what other alternative do you have?

Comment: Which are the alternatives? If you use some kind of transport encryption, such a token is not transmited as clear text

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is better practice to send authentication or authorization tokens in a requests header rather than the body:

```js
// Send a POST request with the access token in the request header.
$.ajax({
    url: 'foo/bar',
    headers: { 'accessToken': 'f0230ce1-5330-41bf-9600-592cfdf3cf0c' },
    data: {
        user_id: 123,
        post_title: 'sample post title',
    }
});
```

You can then fetch this header on the server-side using [`getallheaders()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php):

```php
$headers = getallheaders();
$accessToken = $headers["accessToken"] ?? null;
```